# Find out if a string contains other strings in a data frame

Tags: python, regex, pandas

How do I map rows of one one data frame to values in another one using pandas?

I was working on a market analysis project. The idea is to write a function to identify if the URL is the 'official' URL. There are two data frames

Data Frame 1 would be a list of URLs:

```
Url
----
https://twitter.com/abcd/1223343
https://twitter.com/fegh/3232
https://twitter.com/qwer/w2234
https://facebook.com/ssdf/w1234
...
```

Data Frame 2 would be a list of official handles:

```
Handle_1 Handle_2 Handle_3
-------- -------- --------
aaaa     fegh     qwer
abcd     eeee     NaN
ssss     NaN      NaN
```

The desired output would be able to find out the Handle for each Url
For example, for data frame 1, it should return Handle_1, Handle_2, Handle_3, NaN respectively.

I've tried using python's in operator to handle but didn't really have a clue.

Comment: Hey Derek, welcome to Stack Overflow! I assume you are talking about pandas data frames here, is that correct? In any case, looks like the example you provided is incorrect -- `NaN, Handle_2, Handle_3` should be `Handle_1, Handle_2, Handle_3`, as the first url contains a value from `Handle_1`.

Comment: Hi Nick, sorry for the typo, it should return Handle_1 for the first input. My intent was that if there is no match between the string and the handles, it should return a Null value.

Comment: Great, now it makes perfect sense!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a suggestion: With the DataFrames (as in your example)

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'URL': ['https://twitter.com/abcd/1223343', 'https://twitter.com/fegh/3232',  
                            'https://twitter.com/qwer/w2234', 'https://facebook.com/ssdf/w1234']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Handle_1': ['aaaa', 'abcd', 'ssss'],
                    'Handle_2': ['fegh', 'eeee', np.NaN],
                    'Handle_3': ['qwer', np.NaN, np.NaN]})
```

this

```
platforms = ['twitter.com', 'facebook.com']
regex_str = '|'.join('https://' + platform + '/' for platform in platforms)
df1.URL = (df1.URL.str.replace(regex_str, '', regex=True)
                  .str.split('/').map(lambda l: l[0]))
df2 = (df2.stack().reset_index(drop=False)
                  .drop(columns=['level_0'])
                  .rename(columns={0: 'URL', 'level_1': 'Handle'}))
df1 = df1.merge(df2, on='URL', how='left')
```

produces

```
    URL    Handle
0  abcd  Handle_1
1  fegh  Handle_2
2  qwer  Handle_3
3  ssdf       NaN
```

The fist step is obvious: Remove the `'https://twitter.com/'` part of the URLs. In the second step `df2` is transformed into the following format

```
     Handle   URL
0  Handle_1  aaaa
1  Handle_2  fegh
2  Handle_3  qwer
3  Handle_1  abcd
4  Handle_2  eeee
5  Handle_1  ssss
```

which then allows, as a third step, a `left-merge` on `df1` along the `URL` columns in both frames.

Comment: Thanks, Timus! Another question would be if there are multiple social media platforms, such as Facebook, Twitter, Instagram, are there any possible ways to identify the handles from the list? (see the revised question)

Comment: @DerekLuo I have updated my answer. It works for the urls that you have provided in the example. But there's no guarantee that in works in all cases: You probably have to analyze the the url structure for each platform to find the right way to extract the handles.